# jQuery .wrapAll() resets scroll of nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, wrapall

Please take a look at the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ardoramor/UzJqd/

When the fiddle loads, DIV with class `.wrapper` is scrolled 200px down. This includes all of the nested `.wrapper. DIVs as well. After 5 seconds, trigger`.wrapAll()`will be executed on the children of`.container`. The content of the`.container`class will be wrapped by a new DIV with`.wrapAll`class. You will notice that the red and blue areas jump and you can now see the top``and`` elements. This happens because of wrapping.

**NOTE:** This is a very simplified example. In reality, I will now know the contents of `.wrapper` DIV. Also, there may be multiple such elements with scroll. My question is whether the children of container can be wrapped without resetting their scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Save the scrollTop before wrapping and restore if after wrapping.

```
var st = $( '.wrapper' ).scrollTop();
$( '.container' ).children().wrapAll( '<div class="wrapAll">' );
$('.wrapper').scrollTop(st);
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JR6y8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just put the scroll code after wrapAll function

```
$( '.wrapper' ).scrollTop( 200 );
```

Comment: That will not work if I dont know the contents of '.wrapper'. I should have had clarified that this is a simplified example.

Comment: Use the variable to get scrollTop value and then set it after putting the wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setTimeout( function () {
        $( '.container' ).children().wrapAll( '<div class="wrapAll">' ).scrollTop($('.container').height());
    }, 5000 );
});
```